# AWS CodePipeline: pass Lambda function output to CloudFormation

Tags: lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, artifact

i want to run a CloudFormation template with CodePipeline. This template is expecting an input parameter which needs to contain the current Date/Time. Unfortunately CloudFormation isn't able to generate the current DateTime by itself out-of-the-box.

My approach was first to run a simple Lambda function to create the current timestamp and save it as `OutputArtifacts`. The subsequently CloudFormation task imports this artifact as `InputArtifacts` and gets the value from the DateTime attribut and passes it to CloudFormation via `ParameterOverrides` instruction.

Unfortunately CodePipeline keeps saying the `DateTimeInput` parameter is invalid (obviously GetArtifactAtt lookup failed).
I assume the lambda output (python: print) doesn't get saved as artifact  properly?

Do you know how to pass the lambda output correctly or do you have an idea how to achieve this on a better way?

All pipeline components are defined with CloudFormation as YAML. Here are the relevant parts:

Lambda Function:

```
Resources:
  ...
  GetDateTimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: '10'
      Role: !GetAtt GetDateTimeFunctionExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
                import datetime
                import boto3
                import json

                code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')

                def lambda_handler(event, context):
                  now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
                  responseData = {'DateTime':now}
                  print json.dumps(responseData)
                  response = code_pipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=event['CodePipeline.job']['id'])
                  return response
```

here are the pipeline tasks:

```
Resources:
...
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref ArtifactStoreBucket
        Type: S3
      DisableInboundStageTransitions: []
      Name: !Ref PipelineName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt PipelineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: GetDateTime
              RunOrder: 1
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Invoke
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: Lambda
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                 FunctionName: !Ref GetDateTimeFunction
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: GetDateTimeOutput
            - Name: CreateStack
              RunOrder: 2
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: '1'
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: TemplateSource
                - Name: GetDateTimeOutput
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: REPLACE_ON_FAILURE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref CFNStackname
                TemplatePath: !Sub TemplateSource::${CFNScriptfile}
                TemplateConfiguration: !Sub TemplateSource::${CFNConfigfile}
                ParameterOverrides: |
                  {
                    "DateTimeInput" : { "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" : [ "GetDateTimeOutput", "DateTime" ] }
                  }
```

**Update**: I was to naive and thought there would be a simple way.
Now I know it is a more advanced and manual task just to deliver a simple output artifact with lambda.

Inside the python code one must evaluate the passed `event` dictionary (`CodePipeline.job`) to lookup:
- the predefined OutputArtifacts (S3 Bucket/Key) and 
- temporary S3 session credentials provided by CodePipeline. 
Then a S3 client must be initialized by these credentials. S3 `put_object` needs to run afterwards.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232174

So my question is again: Do you guys have an idea how to achieve this on a better or more simple way? 
I merely want to put the current date and time as input parameter for CloudFormation and don't want to break automation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I wasn't aware of the need to manually handle the output artifacts myself.

Finally this did the trick:

```yaml
  GetDateTimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: '10'
      Role: !GetAtt GetDateTimeFunctionExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
                from __future__ import print_function
                from boto3.session import Session
                from zipfile import ZipFile
                import json
                import datetime
                import boto3
                import botocore
                import traceback
                import os
                import shutil


                code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')

                def evaluate(event):
                    # Extract attributes passed in by CodePipeline
                    job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
                    job_data = event['CodePipeline.job']['data']

                    config = job_data['actionConfiguration']['configuration']
                    credentials = job_data['artifactCredentials']

                    output_artifact = job_data['outputArtifacts'][0]
                    output_bucket = output_artifact['location']['s3Location']['bucketName']
                    output_key = output_artifact['location']['s3Location']['objectKey']

                    # Temporary credentials to access CodePipeline artifact in S3
                    key_id = credentials['accessKeyId']
                    key_secret = credentials['secretAccessKey']
                    session_token = credentials['sessionToken']

                    return (job_id, output_bucket, output_key, key_id, key_secret, session_token)

                def create_artifact(data):
                    artifact_dir = '/tmp/output_artifacts/'+str(uuid.uuid4())
                    artifact_file = artifact_dir+'/files/output.json'
                    zipped_artifact_file = artifact_dir+'/artifact.zip'
                    try:
                        shutil.rmtree(artifact_dir+'/files/')
                    except Exception:
                        pass
                    try:
                        os.remove(zipped_artifact_file)
                    except Exception:
                        pass
                    os.makedirs(artifact_dir+'/files/')
                    with open(artifact_file, 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(data, outfile)
                    with ZipFile(zipped_artifact_file, 'w') as zipped_artifact:
                        zipped_artifact.write(artifact_file, os.path.basename(artifact_file))

                    return zipped_artifact_file

                def init_s3client (key_id, key_secret, session_token):
                    session = Session(aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=key_secret, aws_session_token=session_token)
                    s3client = session.client('s3', config=botocore.client.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
                    return s3client

                def lambda_handler(event, context):
                    try:
                        (job_id, output_bucket, output_key, key_id, key_secret, session_token)=evaluate(event)
                        (s3client)=init_s3client(key_id, key_secret, session_token)

                        now=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
                        data={"DateTime":now}

                        (zipped_artifact_file)=create_artifact(data)

                        s3client.upload_file(zipped_artifact_file, output_bucket, output_key, ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"})

                        # Tell CodePipeline we succeeded
                        code_pipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job_id)

                    except Exception as e:
                        print("ERROR: " + repr(e))
                        message=repr(e)
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        # Tell CodePipeline we failed
                        code_pipeline.put_job_failure_result(jobId=job_id, failureDetails={'message': message, 'type': 'JobFailed'})

                    return "complete"


  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref ArtifactStoreBucket
        Type: S3
      DisableInboundStageTransitions: []
      Name: !Ref PipelineName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt PipelineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: S3Source
          Actions:
            - Name: TemplateSource
              RunOrder: 1
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: S3
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactStoreBucket
                S3ObjectKey: !Ref SourceS3Key
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: TemplateSource
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: GetDateTime
              RunOrder: 1
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Invoke
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: Lambda
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                 FunctionName: !Ref GetDateTimeFunction
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: GetDateTimeOutput
            - Name: CreateStack
              RunOrder: 2
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: '1'
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: TemplateSource
                - Name: GetDateTimeOutput
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: REPLACE_ON_FAILURE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref CFNStackname
                TemplatePath: !Sub TemplateSource::${CFNScriptfile}
                TemplateConfiguration: !Sub TemplateSource::${CFNConfigfile}
                ParameterOverrides: |
                  {
                    "DateTimeInput" : { "Fn::GetParam" : ["GetDateTimeOutput", "output.json", "DateTime"]}
                  }
```

Pretty much overhead for such a trivial task ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Fn::GetParam" instead of "Fn::GetArtifactAtt". According to CloudFormation document, "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" can only get artifact's attribute like BucketName, ObjectKey and URL. "Fn::GetParam" can get an value from a json file in the artifact. Therefore if you can generate the artifact "GetDateTimeOutput" as a zip file, which includes a JSON file (e.g. param.json) with the following content

{
    "DateTime": "2018/10/31 13:32:00"
}

Then you can use { "Fn::GetParam" : [ "GetDateTimeOutput", "param.json", "DateTime" ] } to get the time.

You could either modify your Lambda function to do it, or use a CodeBuild action. CodeBuild takes care of creating the zip, you just need to specify the build commands to create a JSON file in the output folder. You can find more information on how to use CodeBuild in CodePipeline in the following document.

CloudFormation Document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html#w2ab1c13c17b9

CodeBuild Document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pipeline.html